# How to truncate numbers to fit into a specific number of spaces in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

I am still a bit new to programming and very new to Java, the kind of code I want is something like this:

```
double a = 10;
double b = 1234.123;
double c = 123.1234;

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

And I want the output to read like:

```
10
1234.12
123.123
```

So basically, I want the numbers to be truncated to fit the number of spaces specified.  In the above example, I wanted the numbers to fit into a field of 7 digits.  I tried using printf() and NumberFormat, but neither of these seemed to work quite right, what other options do I have?.
Thanks for responding.

EDIT: @Pete, here is what I have been trying.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    double num1 = 123.456789;
    double num2 = 12.3456789;
    double num3 = 1.23456789;
    // create number format object
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    // limits number of fraction digits to five
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(5);
    System.out.println("Using NumberFormat:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("num1 = " + nf.format(num1));
    System.out.println("num2 = " + nf.format(num2));
    System.out.println("num3 = " + nf.format(num3));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Using printf:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%7f\n", num1);
    System.out.printf("%7f\n", num2);
    System.out.printf("%7f\n", num3);
}
```

The output for the above code is:

```
Using NumberFormat:

num1 = 123.45679
num2 = 12.34568
num3 = 1.23457
-------------------------------
Using printf:

123.456789
12.345679
1.234568
```

I am looking for a way to format any number to fit a field with a width of 7, and once the number of spaces is exceeded, it will begin to truncate from the end.  I want a technique that will work regardless of which number is entered.  both printf() and NumberFormat produce a specified number of decimal places, but neither cause my output to be truncated.

Comment: float/double in Java is _not_ an exact precision type.  You should look into using `BigDecimal`, which is exact, and which would make your question more feasible to answer.

Comment: Could you post the code using printf / NumberFormat and the way in which it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat for the purpose. Define a DecimalFormat object in your class

```
private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
```

While printing the values say stored in a variable called result, use below code to print the formatted value:

```
System.out.println(df2.format(result));
```